# Find probability based on cumulative functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a CDF:

$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x\le-2 \\ \frac 18, & -2< x\le -1 \\ \frac 38, &-1< x\le 0 \\ \frac 58,& 0 < x \le 1 \\ \frac 78,& 1 < x \le 2 \\ 1, &x> 2\end{cases}$

Find $P(-1\le X \le1)$, $P(X \le -1$ or $X = 2)$.

I'm not sure whether $P(-1\le X \le1) = F(1)-F(-1)=\frac 12$ or $P(-1\le X \le1) =F(2)-F(-1)=\frac 78 - \frac 18=\frac 68$

Please help me, I have been searching all sources and found no positive results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark:

- The proposed CDF is not a valid cdf, a cdf should be right-continous, which is not the case here.

If we subtract $F(-1)$, we would not have included $P(X=-1)$.

Assuming that the typos are just with the inequality that is rather than $(-2<x\le -1)$, it should be $(-2 \le x < -1)$.

The answer should be \begin{align}Pr(-1 \le X \le 1) &= Pr(X \le 1) - Pr(X < -1) \\
&= F(1) - F(-2)\\
&=\frac78 - \frac18\\
&= \frac68\end{align}

Comment: It means the answer is $\frac 58$?

Comment: I thought you obtain $\frac68$ in the working that you showed in your post?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited my post. However, I don't understand why it takes $F(2)$ while the $x \le 1$ sign. Moreover, your $F(1)-F(-2)=\frac 58$.

Comment: It seems that there is a typo at the question statement.

Comment: I have checked and I have written the same as my book. However, if there were a typo at $-2 \le x \le -1$, $0 < x \le 1$ and $1 < x \le 2$ must also be $0 \le x < 1$ and $1 \le x < 2$?

Comment: Yes, the equality part of the inequalities are at the other side.